# FlowDirection not working

Tags: c#, winforms

I have following code:

```
class NumField : FlowLayoutPanel
{
    private Label label;
    private TextBox box;

    public NumField(string name, Object value)
    {
        label = new Label();
        label.Text = name + ":";
        label.BackColor = Color.Chartreuse;

        box = new TextBox();
        box.Text = value.ToString();

        initializePanel();
    }

    private void initializePanel()
    {
        BackColor = Color.Aquamarine;
        FlowDirection = FlowDirection.LeftToRight;
        Controls.Add(label);
        Controls.Add(box);
    }
}
```

But the label is above the box, not left to it as it should be.
Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `NumField` Width is defaulting to 200.  `label` and `box` are each defaulted to 100.  I'm not sure what the exact numbers are on when a `FlowLayoutPanel` should wrap, but if you increase your control width, they'll sit horizontally to eachother.

Comment: I'm coming from Swing, I'm not used to absolute container sized... Didn't think of it.